# Entity Framework Core multiple relationships to same table

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I have a problem with two references to the same table with different columns:

```
public class MainApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public MainApplicationContext(MainSqlDbContext mainSqlDbContext)
    {
        MainSqlDbContext = mainSqlDbContext;
        this.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
    }

    public DbSet<Organisation> Organisations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrganisationContact> OrganisationContacts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Entity<Organisation>()
          .HasKey(t => new { t.OrgId, t.OrgType, });
      modelBuilder.Entity<OrganisationContact>().Property(p => p.OcsId).HasValueGenerator<SequenceNumberValueGenerator>().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(MainSqlDbContext.Database.GetDbConnection());
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    private MainSqlDbContext MainSqlDbContext;
}

[SequenceNameAttribute("ORGANISATIONCONTACTS", "web")]
[Table("ORGANISATIONCONTACTS", Schema = "dbo")]
[Serializable]
public partial class OrganisationContact
{
    [Column("OCS_ACTIVE")]
    [MaxLength(1)]
    public string OcsActive { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Key]
    [Column("OCS_ID")]
    public int OcsId { get; set; }


    [Column("OCS_NAME")]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string OcsName { get; set; }


    [Column("OCS_ORGANISATION_KEY")]
    [RelationshipTableAttribue("ORGANISATIONS", "dbo")]
    //Relationships
    public int OcsOrganisationKey { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OcsOrganisationKey")]
    public Organisation Organisation { get; set; }


    [Column("OCS_TYPE")]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    [RelationshipTableAttribue("ORGANISATIONS", "dbo")]
    //  Relationships
    public string OcsType { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OCS_TYPE")]
    public Organisation Organisation1 { get; set; }
    public OrganisationContact()
    {
    }

}

[SequenceNameAttribute("ORGANISATIONS", "web")]
[Table("ORGANISATIONS", Schema = "dbo")]
[Serializable]
public partial class Organisation
{

    [Column("ORG_EMAIL")]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string OrgEmail { get; set; }

    [Range(0, int.MaxValue)]
    [Column("ORG_ID")]
    public int OrgId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("ORG_NAME")]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string OrgName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("ORG_TYPE")]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string OrgType { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Organisation")]
    public ICollection<OrganisationContact> OrganisationContacts { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Organisation1")]
    public ICollection<OrganisationContact> ORGANISATIONCONTACTS1 { get; set; }

    public Organisation()
    {
        this.OrganisationContacts = new HashSet<OrganisationContact>();

        this.ORGANISATIONCONTACTS1 = new HashSet<OrganisationContact>();

    }

}
```

I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'OCS_TYPE' cannot be added to the type 'OrganisationContact' because there was no property type specified and there is no corresponding CLR property or field. To add a shadow state property the property type must be specified.

Comment: Use _InverseProperty_ see [EF_InverseProperty](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: i have already try with that

Answer (score 0):

The core issue here is that you define a composite primary key in table *Organisation* but you try to use single fields as foreign keys in table *OrganisationContact*.

If the primary key of the referenced table is composite, the foreign keys referencing it must be composite, as well, consisting of fields of the same number and type:

```
[Table("ORGANISATIONCONTACTS", Schema = "dbo")]
public partial class OrganisationContact
{
    // irrelevant declarations omitted for brevity...

    [Column("OCS_ORGANISATION_ORG_ID")]
    public int Organisation_OrgId { get; set; }

    [Column("OCS_ORGANISATION_ORG_TYPE")]
    public string Organisation_OrgType { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Organisation_OrgId) + "," + nameof(Organisation_OrgType))]
    public Organisation Organisation { get; set; }

    [Column("OCS_ORGANISATION1_ORG_ID")]
    public int Organisation1_OrgId { get; set; }

    [Column("OCS_ORGANISATION1_ORG_TYPE")]
    public string Organisation1_OrgType { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Organisation1_OrgId) + "," + nameof(Organisation1_OrgType))]
    public Organisation Organisation1 { get; set; }
}

[Table("ORGANISATIONS", Schema = "dbo")]
public partial class Organisation
{
    // irrelevant declarations omitted for brevity...

    [InverseProperty(nameof(OrganisationContact.Organisation))]
    public ICollection<OrganisationContact> OrganisationContacts { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(OrganisationContact.Organisation1))]
    public ICollection<OrganisationContact> ORGANISATIONCONTACTS1 { get; set; }
}
```

Some suggestions:

- Please post [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code. There are some exotic attributes (like *RelationshipTableAttribue*) and unknown type references (*MainSqlDbContext*) which has nothing to do with the problem but makes more cumbersome to review the issue.
- Try to avoid hardcoded strings as much as possible. The *[nameof](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/16101a/nameof-operator-a-new-feature-of-C-Sharp-6-0/)* operator has been available for quite a while (since C# 6.0).
- The preferred way to configure your DB mappings is fluent API in EF Core. Data annotation attributes are pretty limited in functionality. (E.g. you cannot define a composite primary key using attributes in EF Core.)

Comment: what about at  OnModelCreating ?

Comment: What do you mean by that? How to this all using fluent API?